# Unix: Find a specific line within files in a directory and comment/replace/remove that line

Tags: unix, sed, replace, scripting

I need to find the line "BATCH NO" in all "setenv.csh" files found in a directory and 
1) remove the line

or

2) replace it with BATCH YES

or

3) comment out the line (add "#" right before "BATCH NO")

Note: The line "BATCH NO" is only found in setenv.csh

I'm thinking the sed command would be required. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to figure out an one line solution. To search for the files, you can do:

```
find . -iname 'setenv.csh'
```

Then, you can use the following function to replace it with BATCH YES

```
update () {
  out=$(echo $1 | sed 's/.csh/.patch.csh/g')
  cat $1 | sed 's/BATCH NO/BATCH YES/g' > $out
  mv $out $1
}
```

Comment: 1) `out=$(echo $1 | sed 's/.csh/.patch.csh/g')` should be `out="${1%csh}patch.csh"`, 2) `cat $1 | sed 's/BATCH NO/BATCH YES/g' > $out
  mv $out $1` should be `sed 's/BATCH NO/BATCH YES/g' "$1" > "$out" && mv "$out" "$1"`. You should also have `local out` as the first line of the function. There are easier ways though, but lets see what the [mcve] looks like once the OP posts it.